# How to get horizontal scroll to navbar in bootstrap 4 when there is lots of nav item

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How to scroll navbar items in bootstrap menu when there is lot of items.

my code is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand name</a>


            <a class="btn btn-danger shadow-sm mr-sm-2 text-white" role="button" href="/demo"> Button</a>



      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">


          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
          ....
        </ul>  
<a href="/search" class="btn btn-info shadow-sm text-white" role="button">Search</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I tried

> .navbar-collapse {
>      max-height: 100vh;
>      overflow-y: scroll;
>   }

But I get a vertical scrollbar in navbar like [this](https://i.ibb.co/SKjkw6q/scrr.png).

Comment: firstly, `overflow-y: scroll;` is not for horizontal, but for vertical. Did you try `overflow-x: scroll;` ?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph It works but it shows scrollbar even though site has width enough to accommodate nav items.

Comment: any fiddle to help? I tried in the fiddle and it looks fine without a scroll. Just try this https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/pqr7sgdz/2/

Comment: please use `overflow-x: auto;` instead of `overflow-x: scroll;` _auto_ would put the scroll bar only when needed why _scroll_ will have the scrollbar always.

Comment: That worked, thanks...

Comment: cheers buddy, keep coding :)

Comment: @Nidhin post the working solution as answer, so it could be accepted

Comment: @Cray its done. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to change the `overflow-x` property from `scroll` to `auto`.

> `overflow-x: auto;` would put the scroll bar only when needed why `overflow-x: scroll;` will have
>   the scrollbar always.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/gqcp5hmd/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have horizontal scroll bar change `overflow-y:scroll` to  `overflow-x :scroll` or `overflow-x:auto`.
`overflow-x:auto`adds  scrollbar if content overflows